# Sum of rational numbers given some properties

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $R(n)$ denote the sum of all positive rational numbers whose numerators and denominators are less than or equal to $n$ and have no common factors. I have estimated this sum to be
$$
\begin{align*}
R(n)=\sum_{\substack{a,b\leq n\\ (a,b)=1}}\frac{a}{b}&=\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{\substack{k\leq m\\ (m,k)=1}}\frac{m}{k}+\sum_{m\leq n}\sum_{\substack{k\leq m\\ (m,k)=1}}\frac{k}{m}-1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}n^2\left(\frac{6}{\pi^2}(\log n+\gamma)+A\right)+O(n),
\end{align*}
$$
using [this technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164569/77474) and some well-known facts from analytic number theory. Here $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $A=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\log n=0.3465...$.

Is there any literature on this sum (or something similar)? And if so, is there an estimate with an error term smaller than $n$?

Comment: For each $n>1$ there are $\phi(n)$ summands and they exactly average to $\frac 12$ because with $\frac an$ you also hav $\frac{n-a}n$.
Hence the exact sum is (noting the special case $n=1$)
$$ R(n)=\frac12 +\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k) $$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The sum $R(n)$ includes fractions exceeding $1$, so you seem to be missing the reciprocals of those terms.

Comment: A concise way to describe the summands is "positive rationals of height up to $n$".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: the proof is a bit too long to post but I'll edit in a general outline.

Comment: @ErickWong: Ok, that good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @ErickWong Oops I took 1\le a\le b\len$ instead of $1\le a,b\le n$. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A005728

Comment: @Charles: What do you mean? The function $R(n)$ is counting the _sum_ of all fractions, not the number of them.

Comment: @CarlNajafi: Yes, and half that number gives the sum of the terms up to 1. (The OEIS includes only integer sequences, so the sum cannot be entered directly.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is anything in the literature, but it can be rephrased in terms of the average of the reciprocals of the [Farey sequence.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence)  See this [related MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41742/what-is-the-sum-of-the-squares-of-the-differences-of-consecutive-element-of-a-fa) for a similar series which yields a nearly identical main term. I include a short proof of your stated result at the bottom - it is better to keep the sum together rather than splitting it up.

Let $F_{k}$ denote the Farey sequence of order $k$, so that when
$k=6$ we have  $$F_{6}=\left\{ \frac{0}{1},\ \frac{1}{6},\ \frac{1}{5},\ \frac{1}{4},\ \frac{1}{3},\ \frac{2}{5},\ \frac{1}{2},\ \frac{3}{5},\ \frac{2}{3},\ \frac{3}{4},\ \frac{4}{5},\ \frac{5}{6},\ \frac{1}{1}\right\}.$$  In particular, $|F_{k}|=1+\sum_{n\leq k}\phi(n)$.  Then your above identity is equivalent to the fact that

$$\mathbb{E}_{y\in F_{N}}\frac{1}{y}=\log N+\gamma-\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{\log^{2}N}{N}\right)$$

To see why, notice that 
$$\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
a,b\leq N\\
(a,b)=1
\end{array}}\frac{b}{a}=-1+\sum_{y\in F_{N}}y+\sum_{y\in F_{N}}\frac{1}{y}.$$
As the Farey sequence is symmetry, we can see that 
$$\sum_{y\in F_{N}}y=\frac{1}{2}|F_{n}|,$$

and since $|F_{N}|=1+\sum_{n\leq N}\phi(n)=\frac{3}{\pi^{2}}N^{2}+O\left(N\log N\right)$,
it follows that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}_{y\in F_{N}}\frac{1}{y} & = & \frac{1}{|F_{N}|}\sum_{y\in F_{N}}\frac{1}{y}\\
 & = & \log N+\gamma-\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{\log^{2}N}{N}\right),
\end{eqnarray*}

> **A short proof:**  Using Möbius inversion, we have that
>   $$
> \sum_{\begin{array}{c}
> a,b\leq N\\
> (a,b)=1
> \end{array}}\frac{b}{a}=\sum_{a,b\leq N}\frac{b}{a}\sum_{d|a,b}\mu(d)=\sum_{d\leq N}\mu(d)\sum_{a\leq\frac{N}{d}}\sum_{b\leq\frac{N}{d}}\frac{b}{a}.
> $$
>   Using the fact that $\sum_{n\leq N}n=\frac{\left[N\right]}{2}\left(\left[N\right]+1\right)$,
>   and the expansion of the harmonic series, this becomes 
>   $$
> \sum_{d\leq N}\mu(d)\sum_{a\leq\frac{N}{d}}\frac{1}{a}\sum_{b\leq\frac{N}{d}}b=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d\leq N}\mu(d)\left(\left[\frac{N}{d}\right]^{2}+\left[\frac{N}{d}\right]\right)\left(\log\left(\frac{N}{d}\right)+\gamma+O\left(\frac{d}{N}\right)\right),
> $$
>   and carefully dealing with the error terms, we arrive at 
>   $$
> \frac{N^{2}\log N}{2}\sum_{d\leq N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}}-\frac{N^{2}}{2}\sum_{d\leq N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}}\log d+\frac{\gamma N^{2}}{2}\sum_{d\leq N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}}+O\left(N\log^{2}N\right)
> $$
>   which becomes
>   $$
> \frac{3N^{2}}{\pi^{2}}\left(\log N+\gamma-\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}\right)+O\left(N\log^{2}N\right).
> $$
>   as desired.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about actually using the Farey sequence (even though this little exercise was inspired by it). I think there is a problem with your calculations though, but I'm not sure what. I plotted your estimate, my estimate and the function $R(n)$ in Mathematica. The estimate you provided clearly diverges from the other two. Ex: $R(100)=17559.4$, my estimate $=17585.1$, your estimate $=16140.8$ and for $R(1000)$ your estimate is off by $14$%.

Comment: @Carl: The estimates are identical, I just missed a negative sign.   Your constant $A$ equals $-\zeta'(2)/zeta(2)^2$.

Comment: Yes, I see now. The zetas in the denominators are supposed to be squared. Thanks!